# Magento: HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: magento-1.9, module

Recently I facing the issue that my site not loading. If i'm checking in `var/log/system.log` file then

> Warning: include(Mage/Usimpleup/Model/Module.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory  in /lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line
>   94

error shows.

Any help should be appreciated.Please review below extension file:-

config.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Unirgy_SimpleUp>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
            <usimpleup remote="http://download.unirgy.com/simple/client_api/version/"
                changelog="http://unirgy.com/support/portal/announcements"/>
        </Unirgy_SimpleUp>
    </modules>
   <global>
      <models>
         <usimpleup>
            <class>Unirgy_SimpleUp_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>usimpleup_mysql4</resourceModel>
         </usimpleup>
         <usimpleup_mysql4>
            <class>Unirgy_SimpleUp_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
               <module>
                  <table>usimpleup_module</table>
               </module>
            </entities>
         </usimpleup_mysql4>
      </models>
      <helpers>
         <usimpleup>
            <class>Unirgy_SimpleUp_Helper</class>
         </usimpleup>
      </helpers>
      <blocks>
         <usimpleup>
            <class>Unirgy_SimpleUp_Block</class>
         </usimpleup>
      </blocks>
      <resources>
         <usimpleup_setup>
            <setup>
               <module>Unirgy_SimpleUp</module>
                <class>Unirgy_SimpleUp_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
               <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
         </usimpleup_setup>
         <usimpleup_write>
            <connection>
               <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
         </usimpleup_write>
         <usimpleup_read>
            <connection>
               <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
         </usimpleup_read>
      </resources>
   </global>
   <adminhtml>
      <layout>
         <updates>
            <usimpleup>
               <file>usimpleup.xml</file>
            </usimpleup>
         </updates>
      </layout>
      <translate>
         <modules>
            <Unirgy_SimpleUp>
               <files>
                  <default>Unirgy_SimpleUp.csv</default>
               </files>
            </Unirgy_SimpleUp>
         </modules>
      </translate>
      <menu>
         <system>
            <children>
               <tools>
                  <children>
                     <usimpleup>
                        <title>Unirgy Installer</title>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/usimpleupadmin_module</action>
                     </usimpleup>
                  </children>
               </tools>
            </children>
         </system>
      </menu>
      <acl>
         <resources>
            <admin>
               <children>
                  <system>
                     <children>
                        <tools>
                           <children>
                              <usimpleup>
                                 <title>Unirgy Installer</title>
                                 <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                              </usimpleup>
                           </children>
                        </tools>
                        <config>
                           <children>
                              <usimpleup>
                                 <title>Unirgy Installer</title>
                              </usimpleup>
                           </children>
                        </config>
                     </children>
                  </system>
               </children>
            </admin>
         </resources>
      </acl>
   </adminhtml>
   <admin>
      <routers>
         <adminhtml>
            <args>
               <modules>
                  <usimpleupadmin after="Mage_Adminhtml">Unirgy_SimpleUp</usimpleupadmin>
               </modules>
            </args>
         </adminhtml>
      </routers>
   </admin>

    <default>
        <usimpleup>
            <general>
                <check_ioncube>0</check_ioncube>
                <dir_perm>755</dir_perm>
                <file_perm>755</file_perm>
            </general>
            <ftp>
                <host>localhost</host>
                <port>21</port>
            </ftp>
        </usimpleup>
    </default>
</config>
```

Model File:-

```
<?php

class Unirgy_SimpleUp_Model_Module extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('usimpleup/module');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Check your model file configuration in `config.xml` and your that class file's folder structure and class name.

Comment: @kunj I have already checked config.xml file for model declaration structure and i think it's proper. any other idea?

Comment: compilation is enable for that website?

Comment: Please share your files.

Comment: @kunj compilation also disabled for site.

Comment: Please share youre model and config file.

Comment: @kunj please review files in question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77615/discussion-between-kunj-and-raj).

Answer (score 0):

you have to Check your module "`Unirgy_SimpleUp`".

This module location will be  `app/code/local/Unirgy/SimpleUp` 
or `app/code/community/Unirgy/SimpleUp`.

Need to replace "**usimpleup**" with "**simpleup**" into your `config.xml` file.

also, replace below code into your Module.php file

`protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('simpleup/module');
    }`

Comment: clear cache and session then retry

Comment: Change something into xml file , you have to flush magento cache once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Your model files and extension folder structure should be this:

`app/code/{{code pool}}/Unirgy/SimpleUp/`

You can continue with `usimpleup/module` model calling.